# Allow users to rate embedded videos in Wordpress site

Tags: youtube, embed, wordpress, forum

I'm an awful programmer, so if there is just an easy plugin, that would be a huge help.

I have a few issues:
1. Is there a plugin that allows visitors to my Wordpress site to easily upload their own Youtube vids for other visitors to see?

1. I'd like to be able to have other visitors rate the user uploaded Youtube vids and then allow other visitors to sort the vids based on rating, is there an easy way to set that up in my Wordpress site?
2. Finally, I'd like a create a forum similar to StackOverflow in my Wordpress site, anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks to everyone in advance.  As you can tell, I'm not very smart with all of this.

Comment: it is possible, but you are going to have to get someone to customize it. you should first play around with the wordpress plugins. it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a WordPress plug in like you describe.  However, if you have the budget for a programmer to do some custom work, I would investigate some existing video plug ins for WP like andrewk suggests and then hire a programmer to implement the voting stuff and any other customizations you need.

I'd also check out the group blogging functionality from Posterous [http://posterous.com].  In the settings panel, there is a setting that you can toggle labeled "Who should be allowed to post on your site?"  You can set it to "Anyone can post and I will moderate."  Users can then submit posts via email.  This solution is ideal for someone with limited programming knowledge since Posterous is easy to use and easy to set up.  But it might be limiting in customizing certain aspects of the site. (E.g., implementing the rating and sorting stuff you describe.)  Learn more about Posterous Groups: http://help.posterous.com/introducing-group-sites-tutorial

Stack Overflow is powered by software called Stack Exchange [http://stackexchange.com/].  You can submit a proposal for a new Stack Exchange community here: http://area51.stackexchange.com.

However, if you wish to set up a forum on your own site there are several hosted forum solutions that you might consider such as http://www.ninjapost.com, http://www.lefora.com, or http://discussions.zoho.com.  A hosted forum solution is advantageous for someone with limited programming knowledge because the set up/installation does not require much programming knowledge compared to a script that you'd install and configure yourself such as phpBB.